# post active 1 or 0 in http body

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I want to put in the body the active value 0 or 1. The code I'm using this code, but I can not send the active status. send only set parameters.

```
public activatehomeboxp(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('homeboxpackage_id', id);
    urlSearchParams.append('token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString();
    return this.http
               .post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.activatehomeboxp), body, { headers })
               .map((response: Response) => {
                   let res = response.json();
                   if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
                       return true;
                   }
               });
}
```

I want something like this:

```
urlSearchParams.append('homeboxpackage_id', id);
urlSearchParams.append('active', '1');
urlSearchParams.append('token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
```

only in this case I always send active 1, I want to send and active 0, not in all cases 1

Can you suggest me any solution please?

Thank you

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: In webservice I want to post homeboxpackage_id, token, and active 1 or active 0. In this code I post only  homeboxpackage_id, token, my question is,How to post in web service and active 1 or active 0 ?

Comment: What do you even mean by "active 1"?

Comment: I just want to send active  1 to activate the product, and active 0 to deactivate the product

Comment: What you are saying is still unclear. Do you mean a field in the post data? For example, with jQuery, $.post('target', {active:1}, function(){ /* callback */ }) ... in this case, how are you determining whether to pass the 1 or 0?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that ?

```
 public activatehomeboxp(id: string, isActive: boolean): Observable<boolean> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('homeboxpackage_id', id);
    urlSearchParams.append('token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    urlSearchParams.append("active", (+isActive).toString());

    let body = urlSearchParams.toString();
    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.activatehomeboxp), body, {
      headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
          return true;
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Missing radix parameter!!

Comment: Add it, it is simple parseInt(isActive, 10). People can't understand what you want, cuz it is simple thing and you can't deal with that and even with parseInt. Site is for developers and questions must be adequate.
I understand that you need a one more flag and show you how to set it. When talking about flags it is better to use Boolean, so variable isActive is boolean, but in database it is tinyint(1) e,g, 0 or 1. So I have added parseInt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now show this: argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: @Aulonna: Just add `.toString()` to turn it into a string.

Comment: @Aulonna there is unary operator (+bool), which returns a string with toString() call. Really you need to learn more about build in functionality.

Comment: @Vayrex Yes, I know, I'm starting with programming. I need support and help. Thanks for the answer. What I am sending to the service is active: NaN

Comment: @Aulonna You need to learn programming =). Support is not working properly when you have not basic knowlage. 
You need to pass "isActive" parameter this method.

Comment: urlSearchParams.append('active', (+'isActive').toString()); --> result NaN